# bootstrap 3 to 4 modal lightbox broke

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, lightbox, bootstrap-lightbox

I'm very new to Bootstrap. I've literally written the code and put the links where instructed. I haven't downloaded any plugins or any other support files as I don't understand it.
Anyway, I've been told (after writing my website) that I should've used Bootstrap 4 not 3. So I'm currently re-writing it. Which is going OK until I got to my image galleries with popup lightbox using modals. I changed the link in the header to the Bootstrap 4.1 version but it's made my lightbox modal popup go wrong in the image gallery. The arrows are in the wrong place to flow forward and back throught the images and the images are now vertical not horizontal in the modal gallery.

This is my Bootstrap 3 version:
http://www.rockclick.co.uk/skating.htm

And this is my Boostrap 4 version:
http://www.rockclick.co.uk/skating1.htm

People keep telling me that Bootstrap is the way to go as it's easier but tbh I'm finding it tricky! Perhaps the more I use it the better it will be? Or am I missing something??

I can't paste all the coding as it's too long, but all I'm using is in the source files for these two pages. 
Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong?

Comment: Your layout has nothing to do with `bootstrap4`. Your modal neither uses bootstrap layout nor styles. Your lightbox modal was from w3schools wasn't it https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp?

Comment: Yes it was from W3schools. Making one from scratch is a little beyond me.

Comment: I've sorted this now. I used a completely new lightbox.